# how to vertically center a div of variable height in a fixed height div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a product Image div, I've tried almost everything, still not able to solve a minor problem, all I want to center my Image vertically in a fixed height box, size of image will vary in every new product image.
here is my code 
HTML:

```
<div class="main-pic">
 <ul>
     <li><img src="images/extra/laptop.jpg"></li>
     <li><img src="images/extra/laptop1.jpg"></li>
     <li><img src="images/extra/laptop2.jpg"></li>
     <li><img src="images/extra/laptop3.jpg"></li>
     <li><img src="images/extra/laptop4.jpg"></li>
     <li><img src="images/extra/laptop5.jpg"></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-pic{width:430px;height:430px;border:1px solid black;margin:20px auto;display:block;float:none;overflow:hidden;}
.main-pic ul{width:10000px;}
.main-pic ul li{width:430px;height:430px;float:none;display:block;margin:-25% auto auto;position:relative;top:50%;}
.main-pic ul li img{max-width: 400px;height:auto;max-height: 400px;width: auto;}
```

FYI I've already tried `verical-align:middle; display:table` and `table-cell`
may be I've been useing them in some wrong way... please help me :(

Comment: so do you want to display 1 image per UL?, kinda confusing since your main container is  430px x 430px or do you want to have them altogether like an image carousel?

Comment: Your title says you want to center a div within a div, but your code doesn't match that.

Comment: Your question is kinda confusing but by looking at your css I kinda figured what you are trying to achieve, I might be wrong thought, look at this http://jsfiddle.net/XYCnk/1/ I removed overflow:hidden and replaced it with scroll so you can scroll from left to right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To vertically center elements in a fixed-height parent element set their `vertical-align: middle`. Add an additional element displayed as an `inline-block` with a zero `width` and full height.

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="height"></div>
    <img ...>
    <img ...>
</div>
```

Sample CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 300px;
}
.height {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
}
.container > img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Demo at [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ozijet/1/edit)

If you know the height of the container you can also set it's `line-height` to the same value instead of using the `div.height`.

Comment: your code is working properly, but one problem why are we using .height ??

Comment: if im using ul after container div, then where should i use .height div, i mean inside the ul or out side the container ??

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;` centeres to the height of the line that the elements are on. `.height` is used to stretch the line to use up the available space. Assuming that you set the height on the `ul` than you could use a `li` element inside the list for `.height`.

Comment: I've put my code like this
html:
`<div class="main-pic">
<ul>
<li><div class="height"></div><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/extra/laptop4.jpg"></li>
</ul>
</div>
`
CSS:
`.height{display: inline-block;  vertical-align: middle;  height: 100%;  width: 0;}
.main-pic ul li img{max-width: 400px;height:auto;max-height: 400px;width: auto;}
.main-pic ul li{width:430px;height:430px;}

`
Still its not working :(

Comment: I didn't do dat :(... I really don't know :(

Comment: With the code like you have it (div>ul>li>img) you could set the container height and `line-height` on the `ul` and set the `li` elements to `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` to make this work.

Comment: got that I had one reset for float:left; that was creating problems, Now its working like charm :)